# Разность месяцев MySQL.

Tags: mysql

Как можно посчитать количество месяцев между двумя датами. С помощью MONTH пробовал, но он не учитывает года.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [PERIOD_DIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_period-diff)
- [DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)

Comment: а приводить к нужному формату date_format?

Comment: Да. `date_format(your_date, '%Y%m')`

Хотя, обе функции не очень хороши. Я бы написал свою. Ну, не знаю, как там на самом деле вам считать нужно. Между 30 января и 28 февраля прошел месяц или нет? А между 30 апреля и 28 мая?

Comment: хммм.. и правда... лучше свою написать...